# Salesforce LWC components - Unable to hit debug point in chrome dev tools - sources tab

Tags: debugging, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I am a newbie to salesforce package development and trying to figure out debugging of the LWC components.

I am able to see the custom LWC components in components/c folder in my sources tab of chrome dev tools but any debug point that i place in any of these js file components is not being hit.

Am i missing something ??

Is my expectation of getting a hit on the debug point in this case,
just like it happens in custom web app js files right..??

I did enable the debug mode for my user and also ensured that the session setting:

**Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components (GA) and Aura components**

is unchecked. I do understand that this setting only applies to having the ability to view the components in chrome dev sources tab, but this was the point till which i reached.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I faced similar problem. I can tell you how I overcome the issue, in addition to steps you mentioned.

I was checking adn adding breakpoint into the wrong file.
Ex. I was checking source tab - *...site.com > components > c > myLWC.js*
But the correct file was - *...site.com > mysitefolder (above components) > s > modules/c > myLWC.js*

And I was able to break the code at breakpoint.

Thanks!